# Generating a list of the degree-$n$ Kronecker polynomials

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, filtering, number-theory

A *Kronecker polynomial* is a polynomial such that

1. Its coefficients are integers,
2. Its roots are on the unit circle or $0$,
3. Its leading coefficient is $1$.

From [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02419.pdf), there are finitely many Kronecker polynomials of a certain degree, and they are of the form

$$f(x)=x^k \prod_j \Phi_j(x)$$

Where $\Phi_n(x)$ is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial, ie. `Cyclotomic[n,x]`.

I want to input $N$ and get the set of Kronecker polynomials of degree $N$. To do this, I think I would do the following:

1. Set up a table for `i=1,2...N-1`, which will be the power of the $x^k$ factor.
2. Find all possible unordered $(l_1,l_2 \dots l_r)$ such that $\deg(\prod\Phi_{l_i}) = N-i$.
3. Compute the polynomial $f(x)$ corresponding to $k$ and $k$'s corresponding $(l_1,l_2 \dots l_r$).
4. Merge the lists.

However, I have no clue how to achieve step 2! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your problem 2 is equivalent to finding the [totient valence function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientValenceFunction.html). See the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A014197), [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/109509), and perhaps [this arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6054), among others.